# Convert a two-column class into a one-column

Tags: two-column, document-classes, conversion, columns

I am using [tccv](http://dev.entidi.com/p/tccv/) document class in order to create my academic and my working cv. However, I believe that an one-column variance of this class could be more convenient for my academic purposes.

For this reason, I wonder how I convert this document class into an one-column, keeping all the other setting the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can find the complete code here: https://github.com/ntd/tccv Just copy all the parts you need in order to get your CV written. The base is a `scrartcl` class which should be installed on your system. You will need LuaLaTeX in order to run this. There is no sense in redesigning a class which is called "Two Column Curriculum Vitae" into a single column document. This is a lot of effort and not suitable for this page, I fear. Just search another template or pick the most beautiful snippets which awoke your interest to this template from Nicola Fontana.

Comment: I am not going to try it, but have you tried simply removing all instances of \twocolumn in the class definition? Seems straightforward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the complete code [here](http://github.com/ntd/tccv). Just copy all the parts you need in order to get your CV written. The base is a `scrartcl` class which should be installed on your system. You will need LuaLaTeX in order to run this.

There is no sense in redesigning a class which is called "Two Column Curriculum Vitae" into a single column document. This is a lot of effort and not suitable for this page, I fear. Just search another template or pick the most beautiful snippets which awoke your interest to this template from Nicola Fontana.

Comment: I did ping you, didn't i?

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes. I believe. The ping got deleted already. I do not think this is an answer... but well. Topic closed. Thanks for 45 Rep and that strange blue hat I am wearing now... :-)